# How to generate reports for QA approval process in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

I have used Promote-build plugin to add QA approvals in my pipeline. I was able to achieve it but i am not sure how to generate reports for approvals. Can we do it through REST API? Please suggest ways

Comment: Have you done any research of your own into the documentation of `Promote-build`, or any features of Jenkins ? APIs are usually quite well documented...

Comment: Yes, I have gone through the promote build document its all about approvals but not mentioned how can we get report of those approvals.